# Python Pandas - something like ISIN but "contains" vs "exact" match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Python Pandas to work with two dataframes. The first dataframe contains records from a **customer database** (First Name, Last Name, Email, etc). The second dataframe contains a list of **domain names**, e.g. gmail.com, hotmail.com, etc.

I am trying to *exclude records from the customer dataframe when the email address contains a domain name* from the second list. Said another way, I need to remove a customer when their email address domain appears on a domain blacklist.

Here are sample dataframes:

```
>>> customer = pd.DataFrame({'Email': [
    "bob@example.com", 
    "jim@example.com", 
    "joe@gmail.com"], 'First Name': [
    "Bob", 
    "Jim", 
    "Joe"]})

>>> blacklist = pd.DataFrame({'Domain': ["gmail.com", "outlook.com"]})

>>> customer
         Email First Name
0  bob@example.com        Bob
1  jim@example.com        Jim
2    joe@gmail.com        Joe
>>> blacklist
  Domain
0  gmail.com
1  outlook.com
```

My desired output would be:

```
>>> filtered_list = magic_happens_here(customer, blacklist)
>>> filtered_list
    Email First Name
0 bob@example.com    Bob
1 jim@example.com    Jim
```

What I've tried so far:

1. To eliminate *specific* email addresses, in the past I've used `df1[df1['email'].isin(~df2['email'])` ... but doesn't help with the use case I'm describing here obviously.
2. I've tried using `df.apply`, but couldn't get the syntax right and I imagine performance would be terrible with the actual data set. Example: `df1['Email'].apply(lambda x: x for i in ['gmail.com', 'outlook.com'] if i in x)`. Although this seems like it should work, I get `TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable`.

Remaining questions are:

1. What's the best approach here?
2. Why is the generator not callable?
3. ... and ultimately, how can I exclude customers from a dataframe when an email address domain exists within an exclusion set?

Comment: Add sample dataframes.

Comment: @VedangMehta good point, I added sample dataframes.

Comment: i've added some comparisons and timings - it might be interesting for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code -

```
import pandas as pd


customer = pd.DataFrame({'Email': [
    "bob@example.com",
    "jim@example.com", 
    "joe@gmail.com"], 'First Name': [
    "Bob", 
    "Jim", 
    "Joe"]})

blacklist = pd.DataFrame({'Domain': ["gmail.com", "outlook.com"]})

invalid_emails = tuple(blacklist['Domain'])

df = customer[customer['Email'].apply(lambda s: not s.endswith(invalid_emails))]

print(df)
```

Output -

```
             Email First Name
0  bob@example.com        Bob
1  jim@example.com        Jim
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that endswith accepts lists. That works perfectly.

Comment: It accepts either tuples or strings, but not lists.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
customer[~customer.Email.str.endswith(invalid_emails)]
```

or

```
customer[~customer.Email.str.replace(r'^[^@]*\@', '').isin(blacklist.Domain)]

In [399]: filtered_list
Out[399]:
             Email First Name
0  bob@example.com        Bob
1  jim@example.com        Jim
```

explanation:

```
In [395]: customer.Email.str.replace(r'^[^@]*\@', '')
Out[395]:
0    example.com
1    example.com
2      gmail.com
Name: Email, dtype: object

In [396]: customer.Email.str.replace(r'^[^@]*\@', '').isin(blacklist.Domain)
Out[396]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: Email, dtype: bool
```

**Timings:**: against 300K rows DF:

```
In [401]: customer = pd.concat([customer] * 10**5)

In [402]: customer.shape
Out[402]: (300000, 2)

In [420]: %timeit customer[~customer.Email.str.endswith(invalid_emails)]
10 loops, best of 3: 136 ms per loop

In [421]: %timeit customer[customer['Email'].apply(lambda s: not s.endswith(invalid_emails))]
10 loops, best of 3: 151 ms per loop

In [422]: %timeit customer[~customer.Email.str.replace(r'^[^@]*\@', '').isin(blacklist.Domain)]
1 loop, best of 3: 642 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:**

`customer[~customer.Email.str.endswith(invalid_emails)]` is a bit faster compared to `customer[customer['Email'].apply(lambda s: not s.endswith(invalid_emails))]` and `customer[~customer.Email.str.replace(r'^[^@]*\@', '').isin(blacklist.Domain)]` is **much** slower